# Largest number on multiplying with itself gives the same number as last digits of the product

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pattern-recognition

What is the largest number on multiplying with itself gives the same number as last digits of the product?

i.e., $(376 \times 376) = 141376$

i.e., $(25\times 25) = 625$

If the largest number cant be found out can you prove that there is always a number greater than any given number? (only in base $10$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any integer $n$,there are $2$ solutions to $x^2 = x \pmod {2^n}$ and $x^2 = x \pmod {5^n}$, which are $0$ and $1$.

Hence by the chinese remainder theorem, there are $4$ solutions to $x^2 = x \pmod {10^n}$. Two of those are the obvious $0$ and $1$, there is one solution which is $0$ mod $5^n$ and $1$ mod $2^n$, and the last one is $0$ mod $2^n$ and $1$ mod $5^n$.

So there is no largest such number.

You can summarize as saying that in the $10$-adic numbers (numbers with an infinite decimal expansion on the left), there are $4$ numbers satisfying $x^2 = x$ :

$...00000000\\
...00000001\\
...87109376\\
...12890625$

Comment: It is not clear why there is no largest such number. Something should be said about why the solution for some $n$ is not the solution for some larger $n$.

Comment: Other than for 0 and 1 solution for n cannot be solution for larger  n because x^2 cannot have all 0's as digits before x

Comment: @DeepakRam: yes, but it should be in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for $k$ so that $k^2\equiv k\pmod{10^n}$, we get
$$
k(k-1)\equiv0\pmod{10^n}
$$
Since $\gcd(k,k-1)=1$, we must have one of
$$
\begin{align}
k&\equiv0\pmod{10^n}\tag{1}\\
k&\equiv1\pmod{10^n}\tag{2}\\
k&\equiv0\pmod{2^n}\quad\text{and}\quad k\equiv1\pmod{5^n}\tag{3}\\
k&\equiv1\pmod{2^n}\quad\text{and}\quad k\equiv0\pmod{5^n}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
The Chinese Remainder Theorem guarantees a solution for each of these.

$(1)$ and $(2)$ lead to $0$ and $1$, so they are bounded.

$(3)$ and $(4)$ lead to more interesting, unbounded solutions. Note that a solution of $(3)$ or $(4)$ for $n$ is also a solution for $n{-}1$ but with another digit added to the left. Furthermore, it cannot be that there is a bounded solution of $(3)$ or $(4)$; that is, one for all $n$. If $k(k-1)\equiv0\pmod{10^n}$ for all $n$, then $k(k-1)=0$; that is, $k=0$ or $k=1$. Therefore, for any $n$, there is a larger $n'$, so that the digit added to the left for the solution mod $10^{n'}$ is non-zero. Thus, there is no largest such number.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers can be arbitrarily large.
Take an arbitrary number $k$, we will produce a number with the desired property that is
at least as big as $5^k$.

$2^k$ and $5^k$ are coprime, so we can find integers $p,q$ such that $p2^k+q5^k=1$, where we
may choose $q$ to be a positive number less than $2^k$.
Now $q5^k$ is our desired number, by our choices it is at least as big as $5^k$ and smaller than $10^k$.
Furthermore $q5^k.q5^k=q5^k(1-p2^k)=q5^k-pq10^k$, so $q5^k.q5^k\equiv q5^k\pmod{10^k}$ as desired.